# Page elements disappearing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, element

I have an issue in a site that I've been working on, and it's only happening in Chrome.

After the page loads (link below), everything but the navigation bars and sponsors banner disappears.  However, if I scroll down, things reappear the way they should be.  Scroll back up, and they disappear again.  I haven't been able to test this out in many other places, but I've tried it on at least one other computer (in Chrome) and the same thing happens.  I was not the one who built the site originally, but I have been working on it for a while now and have a pretty good understanding of it.  However I've never seen anything as weird as this.  Other notes:  Sometimes the whole background and content disappears, sometimes only portions of it.  It's also really laggy, again only in Chrome.

I think this may be JavaScript related, but I don't know.  Can anyone tell me why the page behaves this way?  Maybe how to fix it?  Why it only happens in Chrome?  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Link: http://www.calpolysae.org/main/baja_media.php

Here are a couple screenshots too, to show the difference before and after scrolling down.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7HP2Q5qXoqrTjdwMldBbzRDVm8&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with fixing the error on page : "'jquery' with version '1.10.0' not found! " 
afer that said,
i think it related to the width of that banner:

```
 <img id="banner" style="position:relative; top:-300px; width: 430px; height:auto;display: block;" src="images/SAElogo.png">
```

try to make it smaller , set it to :

```
width: 300px;
```

Comment: So, that works!  Any chance you could explain why things were disappearing?  Also, say I want to have the banner be as big as it was... is there a workaround other than making it smaller and changing the appearance of things completely?

Comment: Actually, I started fiddling with the size of the banner, and it seems the size of the image file was causing the problem as well.  I substituted a compressed and much smaller one, so now I can have it full size and displaying correctly.  Still, can you offer any insight as to why this happens, and only in Chrome?  Thanks so much.

Comment: i'm sorry, i can't be more helpful the code you are using has built all wrong and it's behavior is an unpredictable one. for instance the relative position is playing a significant role for things appearing not right.

Comment: Yeah, I have work to do.  The banner was just thrown into the navigation file so that I didn't have to keep copying code to all the pages individually.  Now that I know it was the culprit I'll do some reorganizing.  Thanks again.